# how to get SSE of a big matrix based on a smaller one

Tags: r

I have two data matrix as below

```
firstMatrix <- matrix(runif(10),500, 100)
   secondMatrix <- matrix(runif(10),500, 25)
```

I want to get the Sum ROOT of square residual from firstMatrix regards to the secondMatrix. this is where I am stuck in

```
myopt3 <- function(firstMatrix,secondMatrix) {
resid2 <- (secondMatrix-firstMatrix[,i])^2
  sum(resid2)
}
```

I want each time, I get the residual of firstMatrix according to the secondMatrix in a way that get the residual for each four columns of firstMatrix based on one column of secondMatrix.

for example

```
(secondMatrix[,1]-firstMatrix[,1])^2
(secondMatrix[,1]-firstMatrix[,2])^2
(secondMatrix[,1]-firstMatrix[,3])^2
(secondMatrix[,1]-firstMatrix[,4])^2
```

then

```
(secondMatrix[,2]-firstMatrix[,5])^2
(secondMatrix[,2]-firstMatrix[,6])^2
(secondMatrix[,2]-firstMatrix[,7])^2
(secondMatrix[,2]-firstMatrix[,8])^2
```

then 
...

until the end and save all the values in another matrix 
This is what I am trying to do on this example data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117458/replicate-rows-of-a-matrix-in-r) you can replicate columns of your `secondMatrix` :

```
secondMatrix = secondMatrix[ ,rep(1:ncol(secondMatrix), times = 4)]
```

Then you do the sum of the squared difference :

```
diff = colSums((secondMatrix - firstMatrix)^2)
```

Comment: I want to use it inside the loop, please modify your answer and give an output so that I can accept your answer

Comment: I don't get your point, my `diff` is what you expect I guess. From a practical point of view, for loop should be banned as very inefficient, or written in C/C++.